# How to consume credential based webservice (asmx) in Asp.net Core web application?

Tags: web-services, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am facing issue while adding asmx service in .NetCore Console application. I am using WCF Connected Service extension as add web reference is not available. So,I followed the same steps which was suggested in following link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/26/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/

After completing all step it provided auto-generated reference class which contains all method as async method. My asmx service required username and password authentication for each method and we pass credential as first parameter of any method.

for example, using web reference my method looks like GetData(Credential credential) but here auto generated class shows this method like
GetDataAsync() so I used the below mention code to pass the credentials before calling my web service method

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myusername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";

It's giving me Not Authorized error, after putting the breakpoints I found that credential was not getting at asmx service.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Previous Approach I Took:**
I ran into a similar issue. I have an MVC Core web application (targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1) and was not able to add a Web Reference the way I used to be able to within previous (non-Core) applications. I was not able to get Connected Services to add a reference to an asmx and allow for the passing of credentials.

To work around this, I created an additional project (a class project also targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1). From there I was able to add a Web Reference the way one could in the past. Within this project I created a class with a publicly accessible method that calls the asmx service.

Then, within my MVC Core project, I set a reference to this additional project and am able to call the public method on the other project.

**Latest and Best Approach I Have Found:**
I fully updated VS 2017 as well as going to this site to get the latest WCF Connected Services extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService).

The AuthorizationSoapHeader was easy to access and set.

```
MySoapClient.EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new MySoapClient.EndpointConfiguration();  
MySoapClient myService = new MySoapClient(endpoint, myURL);              
AuthorizationSoapHeader MyAuthHeader = new AuthorizationSoapHeader();

MyAuthHeader.AppName = FDSServiceAppName;
MyAuthHeader.AppID = Guid.Parse(MyAppID); 

Entry[] entries = MyService.GetUsers().Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and i resolved it owning to  [github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1812)  :

In Reference.cs substitute

```
System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
```

for

```
 System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

This really worked in .net core client app for soap web services